# Can non-functional requirement be represented in a UML diagram

Tags: uml, analytics, actor

I've a system to be represented in UML diagrams (use case,sequence ,activity and class)

The  system has functional &non-functional requierments
The functional requirements could be represented as Use Cases but I don't Know how a non-functional requirement could be represented

Comment: Please check the revision log. You re-entered some of the typo's I fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can represent any kind of requirement in a UML model. Create or use a metaclass named Requirement and stereotype that with `<<functional>>` or `<<non-functional>>`.  Since there are so many different non-functional classifications you can use a tagged value to determine which kind. Now you can `<<trace>>` your use case (or most likely your class design) to those requirements. It's also possible to show the realization of requirements.

Instead of using tagged values you can also simply use packages where you stuff in the single requirements. The minor drawback with this is that you need to check the context of the requirement to find out where it belongs.

[image]

NB: I have not shown the stereotype in the diagram and you are also free to use or omit stereotypes. There is quite some freedom in representing things in UML.

Comment: if I have non functional req. like (your system should implement Search Engine Optimization or SEO and should be protected from attacks like SQL Injection, XSS, File Inclusion) how should I represent this in use case diagram

Comment: You need to split them up into single reqs (Performance "opt. Search eng.", safety:"protect from injection", etc.). Then link them each with a trace as shown above. If you don't know where they end up you can place them sole in a UC diagram an link them up with classes later.

Comment: See my addition in above comment.

Comment: Thomas is right, but I have two additions: (1) The UML specification does not explicitly mention non-functional requirements. The metaclass/stereotype approach can be used for anything. (2) It might be more efficient to maintain your non-functional requirements and your traces in a table instead of in UML.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I usually package NFs accordingly. Why did I forget ist? I should add this to the answer.

Comment: in fact the question describes Functional and NF    but it didn't ask explicity to represent them(NF) so I don't know if to do or not 
@www.admiraalit.nl